# Find last row no in excel in a particular columnno using Apache poi

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

[image: my excel screenshot]

i want to find the row no i.e 10 of value "sam" using columnno 6

any inbuilt function in apache poi like this `col(6).getLastRowNum()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to identify last row from excelsheet. Below code automatically iterate through all rows and identify last row from all columns.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Making of excel file object
        File myFile = new File(CommonMethods.getFilePath("testdata", "Sample.xlsx"));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheet("Logout");
        XSSFRow row = null;

        // Making the object of excel row
        row = mySheet.getRow(0);

        int colCount = row.getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("Column Count :- " + colCount);

        int rowCount = mySheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        System.out.println("Row Count :- " + rowCount);
    }
```

Comment: The assertion: "Below code automatically iterate through all rows and identify last row from all columns." is not true. Instead `Sheet.getLastRowNum` simply returns the biggest row number of the rows collection from the sheet. This is `SortedMap<Integer, XSSFRow> _rows` for `XSSFSheet`and `TreeMap<Integer, HSSFRow> _rows` for `HSSFSheet`. So `Sheet.getLastRowNum` will always be the biggest `Integer` in those `Map`s.